# Get a list of unreadable files using ADB

Tags: adb, backup, external-sd, file-management, data-corruption

I'm trying to make a backup of a dying SD card on my Samsung Galaxy Note 8.

I tried using `adb pull`, better-adb-sync, and other tools. The problem is that, not all files are readable because of the bad state of the SD card. Right now, I have been copying each file name that failed and putting it in a exclude list, but this is extremely inefficient and frustrating.

I wish there was a way to get a list of files that fail to be read, put them on a file, and then do a proper pull of the rest of the files.

---

I opted to use a script that reads a list of files and copies each file one by one, letting the ones that fail... well, fail, and then continue with the next:

```
DEST="$(pwd)/Camera/"
for f in $(cat all-files.txt); do
    echo "Processing $f"
    adb pull $f $DEST
done
```

I will still love to know how can I "test" each file to know if it is readable or not, just to have a list of corrupted files.

Comment: For testing if a file is readable I would avoid adb and directly execute commands inside an `adb shell` on device side. Not sure which command is best to check if a file is readable, but standard Linux tools like `find` (in combination with -exec parameter), `grep -R` or `shasum` may output if a file is not readable.